# Command `run-android` unrecognized - Após instalar o navigation

Tags: react, react-native

Após criar um projeto react-native init teste e instalar o navigation (`npm install --save react-navigation`) simplesmente após isso o comando run-android não é mais reconhecido.
Encontrei diversas formas de correção em alguns lugarem mais pra mim não resolveu.

Alguém sabe dizer exatamente o motivo desse problema?

Comment: Você está executando o comando na pasta raiz do react ?

Comment: Olá, Teria como enviar um print no momento do erro?

Comment: Descobrir que havia um conflito por conta do Yarn. Desistalei o yarn e o problema foi resolvido.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde.

Muitas vezes quando executamos a instalação de uma nova dependência, devemos em seguida executar o comando `npm install` para que o projeto seja todo atualizado.